# How to get a folder/file in local project using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jszip

I have a local web project, with classical folders (css, js etc).

I have a "special" folder in this same project at the same level as js or css folders. This special folder is just a zip folder, inside there are some text files.

In one of my javascript files I'll need to access the content (some text files) of this special folder. I'm using JSZip to read this zip file.

I'm trying to perform it using url but it doesn't work.

```
var zip = new JSZip();
var specialFolder = "starter/special.zip";

zip.loadAsync( specialFolder).then(function(zip){
  <<< ERROR HERE >>>>
});
```

Comment: `<<< ERROR HERE >>>>` — And what does the error message say?!

Comment: @Quentin it says : "Uncaught (in promise) Error: Can't find end of central directory : is this a zip file ?"

Comment: Does it exist on the server?

Comment: If you type the path into the address bar, does it download?

Comment: @evolutionxbox All this is in local

Answer (score 1):

You're passing a filename as the zip content. [`loadAsync`'s document](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/documentation/api_jszip/load_async.html) shows that you're supposed to pass **content**, not a filename.

The [read a file example](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/documentation/howto/read_zip.html) shows loading the content via [`JSZipUtils.getBinaryContent`](https://github.com/stuk/jszip-utils), and then passing it into `loadAsync`:

```
JSZipUtils.getBinaryContent('path/to/content.zip', function(err, data) {
    if(err) {
        throw err; // or handle err
    }

    JSZip.loadAsync(data).then(function () {
        // ...
    });
});
```

---

Re your comment:

> All this is in local

If by "local" you mean `localhost`, that's fine. If by "local" you mean you're using a `file://` URL, in many browsers ajax won't work and loading the data won't be possible. Instead, use a local web server process (a simple one is easy to install and use) and use `localhost`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, yes when I say "local" it's a file:// URL

Comment: @Sushi: Yeah, some browsers (Firefox) allow ajax to local files like that, others (Chrome) don't.

Comment: Yes, any other solution eccept using localhost please ?

Comment: @Sushi: Use Firefox or another browser that lets you do ajax to `file://` URLs.

Comment: Yes it works well on Firefox, so there is no way for all browsers using ajax ?

Comment: @Sushi: No. As I said above, some browsers (such as Chrome) do not allow ajax from `file://` URLs.

Comment: Ok thank you alot, I'll host my web application, so it will use https protocol, so it means I wont have problems right ?